# How to append new values to csv cells with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to create something like a csv file database for a school project.
I have a list of values/rows that stay the same like the UID but also values that I want to keep track of like a timestamp. Simplified example below:

| UID | Timestamps |
| --- | --- |
| First | Date1,Date2,Date3 |
| Second | Date1,Date2,Date3,Date4,Date5 |

What I get right now is:

| UID | Timestamps |
| --- | --- |
| First | Date1 |
| Second | Date1 |

Is there an elegant way to do the following in pandas that is somewhat fast and doesn´t require iteration ? :
If a specific UID has been found append the timestamp to the associated cell.

EDIT:
I hope I can make my question more clear now (sorry I am new to this). I want to scrape a list of links (UID) and add a timestamp everytime the script detects a change in an html element associated with the link. The logic for checking if a change has been made does not exist yet.

```
links_extended=[]
datestamp_extended=[]
while(True):
    try:
        a = driver.find_element_by_id('thermoplast').find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
        links = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in a]
 
        datestamp = []
        now = datetime.now()
        for date in links:
                date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                datestamp.append(date)

        datestamp_extended.extend(datestamp)
        links_extended.extend(links)
#if no next link is found while loop ends
    except:
        hot_dict = {'Link': links_extended, 'Datestamps': datestamp_extended}
        hotlist_df = pd.DataFrame(data = hot_dict)
    break
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: it is unclear what is the input and output, can you make it explicit?

Comment: Please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output.